# I just built an 18650 battery. I need to know if I can use this power adapter/charger for this BMS

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, charger, bms, 18650

I just built my first battery. I need to know whether I can use a 12 V, 1.8 A power supply that I fished out of a box of electronics I have. It was for an Apple router or something.

The battery is a 12 V, 3s2p 18650. I read somewhere that a switching power supply which I believe is this type can cause ripple, and will throw off a BMS.

I have included a link to the BMS. The manual that came with the BMS says that I can charge the battery through the common charge/discharge port on the BMS. The manual states that the balance charge limits the current to 100 mA. Does that mean no matter what kind of charger I use, that the battery will be limited to 100 mA?

The manual also states something about using a low current charging supply but it not really being necessary only when using "larged unmatched cells or high capacity". I guess I can't show pictures here. Here is the link though.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/184567779219

Also let me know that if this kind of charger does cause ripple, is there some way I can limit current? I have many electronics around I can gut and maybe pull something out/desolder to use for this purpose? I really want to get this done tomorrow, I am so close. I want to start charging it tomorrow in my isolated environment.

Comment: Please link the manual of the BMS. Also link the manual of the charger. Buying stuff from eBay (and the like) is not recommended unless there is a clear link to the quality system employed during manufacturer (especially with something that can easily catch fire if misused). Desoldering stuff from old PCBs is also not recommended for the same reason.

Comment: No, you can't simply use a power supply to charge batteries. You need a charger. I can't recall how many time this same basic question is asked here already and I'll try to find a duplicate to close this.

Comment: _"Does that mean no matter what kind of charger I use, that the battery will be limited to 100 mA?"_ Absolutely not! Your charger must have its own CC limit.

Comment: From the specs on the eBay listing. it looks like this module charges at 10 amps. You might try asking the seller, but I think you'd be safer to buy a dedicated charger with the proper current for your 18650 cells.

Comment: Right that is how I found this forum, other answer on here. However I am slightly confused because there was a post about a boom box and someone doing what I am doing. Someone just said I need to limit the ripple. The manual says the BMS is capable of charging and discharging. IT shares a common charge and discharge port.

Comment: Also I plan on doing the first charges and discharges outside in a giant sand pit well away from any structures,tree, vegetation, etc. WIll check the cells for heat, they are used but in very good condition are are very good cells

Answer (score 2):

Power supply ripple is not your problem here. The BMS should never see the power supply directly; there should be a Li-ion charger inbetween.

A BMS is not a charger; you need a proper Li-ion charger to charge your battery pack, not just a power supply.

As far as I can tell from the description and photos of the BMS you link to, it is a cell-balancing BMS that doesn't include a charger. Such a BMS offers protection for a battery pack against over/undervoltage, high currents, etc. when something goes wrong, but it is not a charger.

The 100 mA mentioned refers to the balancing current between cells, not the normal charging current, so no, the charging current isn't limited to 100 mA.

I can't tell if this BMS is a good match for your battery pack without specs of your battery pack; it appears to be intended for fairly high currents and won't protect a small battery pack against too high a charging/discharging current.

Even if it is a good match, *it still is not a charger*; you need a proper Li-ion charger to charge your battery pack.

Comment: Allright well if the seller doesn't respond Ill return the BMS and buy the IMAX B6. I think I already understand how to hook up the BMS. The whole point of this was for me to start small building a battery so I can eventually work my way up to a much much much larger battery for an electric motorcycle.

Comment: Why do I see guys on YouTube all the time hooking up just the straight voltage of the battery and charging that way? Also I've been using the wrong chargers for my ebike batteries forever and the BMS and battery is so good I've done thousands of charges. I don't think the charger I have does a CC and CV cycle. I don't even think my $40 WATE does that either...

Comment: Look anywhere online and you'll see people doing stupid things.

Comment: @MarkIII, You are free to disregard what you read here. However, my guess is that your ebike charger does have a CC / CV charge cycle or the battery has a built-in charging circuit and not just a BMS. Hooking up a straight voltage to an unprotected LiIon cell might work a few times, but it will quickly damage (possibly violently) your battery. LiIon charge circuits exist for a reason.